# decimal positions to decimal via hex? (python)

Tags: decimal, python, hex

Sorry for confusing title, but i did not know what to call this...

So in python I'm reading a binary file via an addon (intelhex).

This gets me the values for each byte loopin through it

```
for x in range(start_addr,end_addr):
    print ih[x]
```

gives:

```
1
79
60
246
```

which is the same as:

```
01
4F
3C
F6
```

I want the decimal value of `014F3CF6 = 21970166`

Is the best approach to just convert the decimals to hex and then concatenate the hex values and the convert to decimal again?
Best being most understandable(pythonic) and/or most efficient

EDIT: To clarify what i want:

I want to convert [1,79,60,246] to 21970166

(since the list is the same as `[01,4F,3C,F6] which is 014F3CF6 which is 21970166)`

Comment: realised that as well, fixed now i hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `intelhex`, I presume you are doing something like

```
import intelhex
ih = intelhex.IntelHex('myfile.hex')
```

Instead of reading bytes one at a time, like

```
>>> ih[0x01c200]
224
>>> ih[0x01c201]
165
>>> ih[0x01c202]
230
>>> ih[0x01c203]
246
```

you can do

```
s = ih.gets(0x01c200, 4)      # "\xe0\xa5\xe6\xf6"
```

then convert to int like

```
import struct
i = struct.unpack('>I', s)   # (3768968950L,)
```

This can then be packaged up as

```
def getInt(ih, addr):
    return struct.unpack('>I', ih.gets(addr, 4))[0]

getInt(ih, 0x01c200)    # -> 3768968950
```

**Edit:**

Be aware that `ih[undefined_addr]` returns 255, while `ih.gets(undefined_addr, 1)` throws a NotEnoughDataError instead. In fact, `ih.gets(addr, n)` throws NotEnoughDataError if any byte in [addr:addr+n] is undefined.

If you do ih.dump('dumpfile.txt'), any bytes not defined in the .hex file show up as '--'; this may make it significantly easier to debug. I suggest you do a file dump, pull it up in a text editor, and take a look at bytes 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i really wanted, but i did not manage to find it myself!

Comment: Also made use of this, try: mystring = ih.gets(0x20,4) except intelhex.NotEnoughDataError: print "There is not enough data at that location"

Comment: If you do `ih.dump()`, what does it show at memory location 0x20? Are you sure you are looking for a 4-byte int, not a 2-byte shortint?

Comment: I'm certain of the value I'm getting, since the script is comparing it against an excel sheet to find differences and similarities.

Answer (score 3):

In python integers are not "decimals" or "hex". They are string representations of numbers. To convert a decimal string to int, use `int('12345', 10)`; to convert a hex string, use `int('1234ABC', 16)`. To convert integer to decimal string representation, you use `str(12345)`, to convert to hex string, use `hex(12345)`.

Furthermore, you should see the module `struct` and consider using it to convert binary data to integers.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
s = 0
for i in bytes:
    s = s * 256 + i
print s
```

Besides, 79 is `0x4F`, not `0xF4`. `0xF4` is 244.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> int('014F3CEC', 16)
21970156
```

This means you should concatenate the strings to one string which contains the hexadecimal number. You can do that as follows:

```
>>> ih = [1, 79, 60, 236]
>>> ih_s = [hex(i)[2:].zfill(2) for i in ih]
>>> ih_s
['01', '4f', '3c', 'ec']
>>> hex_string = ''.join(ih_s)
>>> hex_string
'014f3cec'
```

Comment: Great, took some time to understand hex(i)[2:].zfill(2) though

Comment: An alternative to the `zfill` would be to use string formatting:  `'{0:02x}'.format(i)`